# How to specify z-index for a panel

Tags: wpf, panel, z-index

Hi I'm new to WPF and I want to place a `Panel` upon a `StackPanel` and show and hide it in my window without using `Canvas` and changing positions and size of other controls or the window.
Something like the fallowing image which the solution explorer is opened on another `Panel`, and as we see the user even can change the position of the `Panel`.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you want to use a canvas?

Comment: If you want to completely hide it, you can change Visibility.

Comment: @chibacity :i have no problem with hiding and showing it . the problem is that i want to open the panel on the stack panel

Comment: i told im new to wpf and i dont know concepts well

Comment: do you want to change size of the controls inside the stack panel?..or in the window? can u add the xaml in your question,that would make a better clarification about this.

Comment: @Shebin: take a look . thank you Shebin.

Comment: @Mohsen Have you considered opening a new modal window to display your control? It certainly looks like a dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `Grid` as the Root Layout and a `StackPanel` on that, you can still use `Canvas`.

```
Canvas.SetZIndex(<YourPanelYouWantInFront>, <LargeValue (100)>);
```